# Retrieve a database record using a value in url without $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

Dear whom that may be able to assist.

Link - https://develop.hangoutsdubai.ae/category-beach-entertainment.php

Currently I am using $_POST method for my listings to be able to retrieve the record in the database as a single page listing.

On the above link page, I will add the following to preview :

I am using below $dashedURL to remove %20 in URL and replace with '-'

//############# REPLACE URL %20 WITH DASH (-) #############//

```html
$string = 'category-beach-entertainment-single-profile.php?'.$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing_rows['nvenueName'].'';
str_replace('%20', '-', $string);
$dashedURL = str_replace(' ', '-', rawurldecode($string));
```

//############# PART OF FORM BEING SUBMITTED #############//

```html
<!-- CATEGORY BUTTON -->
<form method="post" action="'.$dashedURL.'">
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="'.$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing_rows['nmainCategory'].'" class="singleProfileDetailsCategory">
      <input type="hidden" name="txtnid" value="'.$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing_rows['nid'].'">
    </div>
</form>

<!-- H3 VENUE TITLE -->
<form method="post" action="'.$dashedURL.'">
    <div>
      <span class="name" style="display:none;">'.$venueName.'</span>
      <input type="submit" value="'.$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing_rows['nvenueName'].'" class="name singleProfileDetailsVenueName" itemprop="name">
      <input type="hidden" name="txtnid" value="'.$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing_rows['nid'].'">
    </div>
</form>
```

//############# ON SINGLE PAGE #############//

```html
$txtnid = $_POST['txtnid'];
$sql_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing = "SELECT * FROM tblvenueListingsBeachEntertainment WHERE nid = $txtnid";

//CONNECT TO MYSQL SERVER
require('inc-conn.php');

//EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT
$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing = mysqli_query($vconn, $sql_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing);

//CREATE AN ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
$rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_BeachEntertainmentVenuesListing);<br><br>
```

Currently my issue is when I copy the single page URL of the venue and would like to share it with someone, the record will display blank. So if I don't select the venue through the main listing page : https://develop.hangoutsdubai.ae/category-beach-entertainment.php it won't display because of $_POST.

For example : Copy this link of a venue and open in a new window or cognitive window and it will display a blank record : https://develop.hangoutsdubai.ae/category-beach-entertainment-single-profile.php?Venue-9-Name

Is it possible to use a different method in order to retrieve all the data from a record without using the main page with all the listings?

The reason is for in case some one would want to share the link of a specific venue but it will show no data. I have tried couple of things but getting stuck. According to my hypothesis there should be a variable that retrieves the name of the venue in the url and retrieve the unique id from that record, then display the data accordingly. Sort of struggling to figure this one out. Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Um... use `$_GET`?

Comment: Robbie is correct.  You could also use $_REQUEST (for HTTP GET, POST and COOKIE).  One thing you need to note - if you are parameter passing in URI string you need to use name value key pairs (i.e. make sure to name the parameter you are passing with a key - e.g. ?venue=Your Venue Name)

Comment: pass the post params in the url as a querystring, mysite.com/list.php?value=xyz&date=2018-11-20 etc

Comment: Thanks Robby and Cherry, I have replaced $_post in form that gets submitted with $_GET and tried it out, but its on the single page that displays the actual details where I am getting stuck. I have done some research about $_REQUEST and COOKIE but not 100% sure how to incorporate it with my code above, any chance for a small example please of what Cherry has mentioned.

Comment: Bsienn, thanks. Are you reffering to an example such as this : https://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php

Comment: I managed to get it to work thank you guys, I had an error in my code and thus it caused it not work properly. Thank you for your time guys, I appreciate it.